# office 365 suite bar Notification pane

Tags: notifications, office365-apps

I am trying to integrate few LoB apps with office 365. There are certain important alerts/notifications from these apps that we would like to display in the notification pane available in the office suite bar(this is bell icon we see on the right side of the suite bar)
I am not able to find any api to help me with this, can anybody please suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks!
Magu